# Accidentally enter "crontab" without -e

Tags: 14.04, cron

Now my root crontab is entirely blank.

I enter some crone tasks into this blank crontab(I typed crontab -e again). Even though I see cron is running(pgrep cron returns a number), no cron job is carried out.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you add anything to your crontab before this?

Comment: yeah. I had a bunch of cron tasks in the old crontab that is now deleted.

Comment: Recovering those could be hard/impossible.  This is the root or the system-wide crontab?

Comment: Do you have any idea why my second cron is not running?

*/1 * * * * python /root/vine/hei.py
48 22 * * * python /root/vine/hello.py

I waited from my local time 22:46. Only the first one was run and the second job was not.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not an expert on Cron. I'll take a look though and see if there's some explanation.